# Tiny script logic which connects to database and sends reply to application

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a painful issue in the following code. My application connects to this script called main.php and sends username and password to it. The script then checks the credentials in the database and replies positively to my application if credentials are correct and negatively if incorrect. To be more specific, it just checks usergroup memberships and sends reply back. Now the issue is that it always sends negative reply. Can you tell me where I am wrong?

```
    <?php

    function append_file( $filename, $newdata )
    {
            $f = fopen( $filename, "a" );
            fwrite( $f, $newdata );
            fclose( $f );
    }


$userAgent          =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$m_pUsername            =   $_POST['user'];
$m_pPassword                =   $_POST['pass'];
    $m_pDate                        =   date(DATE_RFC822);
    $m_pIP                          =   $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ];


    $conf['host']           = 'localhost';
    $conf['user']           = 'XXX';
    $conf['pass']           = 'XXX';
    $conf['database']       = 'XXX';



if( !$m_pUsername || !$m_pPassword )
    die("g_requireUpdate");



    $con = mysql_connect($conf['host'],$conf['user'],$conf['pass']) or die ("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db($conf['database'])or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

    $salt = $row['salt'];
    $md5_pass = MD5(md5($m_pPassword) . $salt);
    if($m_pUsername == $row['username'] &&  $md5_pass == $row['password'] )
    {

        if( $row['usergroupid'] == '5' || $row['usergroupid'] == '9' || $row['usergroupid'] ==     '7' || $row['usergroupid'] == '6' || $row['usergroupid'] == '71' || $row['usergroupid'] == '72'      )//VIPS + STAFF
{
            print("g_userValid ");

            append_file( "access_log.txt", "($m_pUsername) \t  ($m_pIP) \n");
        }
        if( $row['usergroupid'] == '2')//NON VIP
                    {
            print("g_userNormal ");
            exit;
                    }
        if( $row['usergroupid'] == '8')//BANNED
                    {
            print("g_userBanned ");
            exit;
                    }
    }
}


append_file( "access_log.txt", "($m_pUsername) \t  ($m_pIP) \t \n");
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: why are you selecting every user and looping though in PHP you should be selecting only the user based from their username in MySQL

Comment: Why are you fetching ALL of your users, when you only want one specific account to test? `select * from users WHERE username='foo'` would make far more sense.

Comment: @cmorrissey In my application, the user will type username and password and then his account needs to be checked with this script.

Comment: @MarcB In my application, the user will type username and password and then his account needs to be checked with this script.

Comment: the way you are currently doing it is not right at all, you should be using a select statement like the example @MarcB gave and I suggested

Comment: @cmorrissey Yea I get that, but still the script worked before, do you see anything that is actually wrong and makes it not work properly.

Comment: If the script worked before, what has changed since then? Could there be an external change like the database credentials (or even server address), field names, do you still pass the values in POST? Also, when you say "it always sends negative reply", does it mean "g_userBanned" or just nothing?

Comment: @Cyclofenil: that's fine, but your code is the equivalent of going to a grocery story, buying up ALL of the items, driving them home, then sorting through them and throwing out everything except the chocolate bar you wanted. It's HIGHLY inefficient.

Comment: @Naomi I am getting g_requireUpdate always. Database credentials were changed, but of course I added in the good info. Field names all the same. I am passing the values in POST, yea.

Comment: Then obviously there is something wrong with the parameters... are you sure the parameter names are good? Your code return this value only `if( !$m_pUsername || !$m_pPassword )` and both values are taken directly from the `$_POST`...

Comment: @Naomi Thanks so far! The params are good because if I run query in phpmyadmin it works, but when I run it as a script it doesn't. Can you enlighten me please. Is the logic behind the script bad and causing timeout on network level. Is there any way to optimize it. I am not experienced php coder so I would appreciate it if you could fix this for me and would offer you reward if that is accepted on stack overflow.

Comment: Are you sure the params are good in the script you're calling it from? If you keep getting 'g_requireUpdate' and the only place you output this message is in an `if( !$m_pUsername || !$m_pPassword )`, then it means that `$m_pUsername` or `$m_pPassword` (or both) evaluates to false (probably meaning they are empty, unless you're passing 0's to them)... It cannot be anything else as it's the only place where you output this message.